# Disabling Touch Gestures in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gesture, windows-11

I am struggling a lot with disabling touch gestures for my application.
Idea is to make it possible to hold the button (fire Mouse Down and Mouse Up events).
Default behavior is a "Press and Hold" which emulates right-click and I have to "scratch" the button for "holding" it. Not ideal, I would say :D

There are solutions available that I have tried but they seem to be outdated (or maybe I am doing it wrong)

I am trying to use SetProp

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetProp(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString, IntPtr hData);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool RegisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint ulFlags);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern short GlobalAddAtom(string atom);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr RemoveProp(IntPtr hWnd, string atom);

public bool EnableTabletGestures(bool enable)
{
    var hWnd = Handle;

    long num = 0L;
    string atom = "MicrosoftTabletPenServiceProperty";
    num = GlobalAddAtom(atom);
    if (num == 0L)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (enable)
    {
        return (RemoveProp(hWnd, atom).ToInt64() == 1L);
    }
    int num2 = 0x1010019;
    return (SetProp(hWnd, atom, new IntPtr(num2)));
}
```

I have tried calling EnableTabletGestures(false) from constructor, Load method and even manually with a button click, to make sure window is fully rendered at this point. Nothing helps, I still see animations and can't do normal "long press".

Another possible solution was Stylus.SetIsPressAndHoldEnabled, but that requires me to use "System.Windows.Inputs" which is conflicting with existing code and still can't do it's job since "can not convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'

.Net framework is 4.8, and target machine is running Windows 11

A help would be highly appreciated!

UPD:

I was also exploring WndProc, but can't make it work properly.
I tried adding PreFilterMessage to my Program.cs, and filtering everything between WM_TABLET_DEFBASE and WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS (not sure if that's right), still no luck. I can only successfully filter all the touch events by discarding WM_POINTERDOWN and WM_POINTERUP.

That's the current code from my WndProc override that I expect to work, but it really does nothing

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS)
        {
            m.Result = new IntPtr(TABLET_DISABLE_FLICKS);
            DefWndProc(ref m);   
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

I have placed it inside my form's class. Would be really great if you take a look and tell me what exactly goes wrong here. It seems like m.Msg == WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS never actually ocures

Comment: have you considered a repeatbutton?

Comment: You have to consider: [Stylus.SetIsPressAndHoldEnabled does not work when Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.EnablePointerSupport is enabled](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5939) if you want to use WPF elements for this. Otherwise override WndProc of a custom Control and discard all messages that don't fit the behavior you're looking for

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tablet/wm-tablet-querysystemgesturestatus-message

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks a lot for suggestions! Made and upd in the post

Comment: This seems like a mistake. Those gestures exist for a reason, and it's poor practice to create UI patterns that interfere with them.

Comment: Counterintuitively, to avoid responding to touch you have to enable touch support on the window (so you get distinct messages for touch instead of having them automatically mapped to mouse events), and only then can you identify and ignore the touches.

Comment: I am actually calling RegisterTouchWindow(this.Handle, 0) inside Load method, but that does not help register WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS. Regarding "poor practice"- that is a very specific app for one particular machine with one user.

Comment: Problem "solved" by switching to WPF. It's button has StylusUp and StylusDown events, and Stylus.SetIsPressAndHoldEnabled has disabled press and hold animation, so button works the way I need.